# How can I get data from a single field into a variable from an SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, cursor

I'm working on my first android app and have an SQLite database set up and working with it, I've been able to successfully use a cursor to retrieve some data and used SimpleCursorAdapter to make the data appear as a list.

I'm now looking to *retrieve a specific field* and *put the result into a float variable*. However all the examples i find online seem to expect you to be handling large retrievals with multiple rows/columns and they've all been adapted into lists or arrays. **I can't figure out how to just get the contents of that one field into a variable.**

I tried using `myVariable = cursor.getFloat(0)` which i think is along the right lines but i couldn't get that working either.

Every time i run my application i just get `null pointer exception` errors, I've tried some `try catch` blocks but I'm new to all this in general and haven't had any success in troubleshooting. It might be something a simple as a query typo..

I'll include the bit of code involved below, but any suggestions general or specific are welcome, Thanks for taking the time to look.

```
public void Main(){

    //gets the rowId we put with the intent from Budget.java, sets a default value of -1 'incase.
    selectedRowId = getIntent().getLongExtra("rowId", -1);
    Cursor costCursor= FindBudgetForId(selectedRowId);
    MyText(costCursor, selectedRowId);

}

public Cursor FindBudgetForId(long selectedRowId){

    SQLiteDatabase db = budgetData.getWritableDatabase();
    String rowBudgetQuery = "SELECT BUDGET_AMOUNT FROM CAT_BUD_TAB WHERE _ID="+ selectedRowId;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(rowBudgetQuery,null);
    startManagingCursor(c); 
    return c;


}

public void MyText(Cursor costCursor, long selectedRowId){      
    TextView whatDoText=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.keypad_text);
    whatDoText.setText("row: " +(String.valueOf(selectedRowId)));
    //set the current  budget amount in the edit text box
    retrievedAmount = costCursor.getFloat(3);
    EditText inputHint=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.cost_input);
    inputHint.setText((String.valueOf(retrievedAmount)));

}
```

Comment: your query only selects 1 field, so the index 3 is out of bounds. you should use cursor.getFloat(0)

Comment: @king_nak: of course thanks for pointing that out, still cant get it to run but that's one less mistake thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that when `SqliteDatabase#rawQuery` returns a Cursor, it is initially positioned *before* the first result. So, in order to actually read a value from the result you get (without getting NullPointerExceptionExplosionDeath), call `cursor.moveToFirst()` before you get the float. I've been bitten by that before.

Comment: oh thanks for the idea, but before the query you say? how can it move the cursor to the first position without me telling it what table i want it to deal with? anyway thanks for the advice, i tried doing it before and after, but no luck so i think the problem must be somewhere else. Thanks anyway i'll be sure to keep what you said in mind!

Comment: Ah sorry if it wasn't clear. After your query to the database (`rawQuery`), the Cursor that is returned is *pointing* at nothing (the position before the first result - like a -1 index). So before you call `getFloat`, *that's* when you call `moveToFirst()`. Does that help?

Comment: Hey, just thought i should mention that this wasn't actually my problem ( it turns out i wasn't passing the context to my sqliteopenhelper class properly, but once i'd done that..) it turned out to be extremely helpful as i knew exactly how to handle the cursor out of bounds errors that came after, so thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can get data like

```
    Cursor c =//Query;
    int numRows = c.getCount();
if (numRows > 0) 
    {
    c.moveToFirst();
    While(numRows>0) // or for loop
    {
          String strName = c.getString(0);
              Int i = c.getInt(1);
              numRows--;
    }       
    }
```